# Proof that any commutative family of unbounded self-adjoint operators has a "generating" operator

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

In *Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians* by Leon A. Takhtajan, the author remarks on page 73:

> According to von Neumann's theorem on a generating operator, for every commutative family $\mathbf{A}$ of self-adjoint operators (not necessarily finite) on a separable Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ there is a generating operator — a
>   self-adjoint operator $R$ on $\mathscr{H}$ such that all operators in $\mathbf{A}$ are functions of $R$.

Here self-adjoint operators need not be bounded.

Where can I find a proof for this theorem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A proof can be found in von Neumann's "Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics". But beware: the book is from the 1920s and the style reflects this.

Comment: Reading the text again, that reference will likely not satisfy you. Von Neumann has a procedure where he discretises the spectrum of any self-adjoint operator arbitrarily finely, so that everything has a point spectrum. In the book he shows the statement then for (possibly unbounded) self-adjoints with a point spectrum for which the projections $P_A(\lambda)$ all commute that there is a common root/generator. The general case is supposedly carried out in [this](https://eudml.org/doc/159483) paper, but its in german, from 1931 and basically unreadable.